# Better way to open modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have 2 ways to open my Form Modal. I wonder which is a better way? And, with solution one, will value of newStaff be delay 1 stay before the modal shows up? thanks:

```js
 const [newStaff, setNewStaff] = useState(null);
  const [showFormModal, setShowFormModal] = useState(false);
 const handleEditDropdownBtn = row => {
    setNewStaff(row.original);
    setShowFormModal(true);
  };
```

and this

```js
 const [newStaff, setNewStaff] = useState(null);
  const [showFormModal, setShowFormModal] = useState(false);
 const handleEditDropdownBtn = row => setNewStaff(row.original);
 useEffect(() => {
    staffToDelete
      ? setShowDeleteWarningModal(true)
      : setShowDeleteWarningModal(false);
  }, [newStaff]);
```

I tried both, first solution sometimes and somehow has newStaff value delays 1 state that when open Modal, it doesn't appear anything.

Comment: I'd say the first one is better, cause you by setting new state it will queue your change but won't affect immediately, so If you set two states back to back. It will create a queue that will re-render component (modal here) once. on the other hand, for the second example it renders **twice**, one for newStaff state change and the other is for when updating setShow of a modal.

Comment: @Re9iNee Hi Re, thank you for your answer. So for the first case, will there be any chance that newStaff received a value after FormModal is opened, leading to FormModal not having a default value?

Comment: Of course, @Long.TH you can pass data from props into state (instead of null)